# Basics of Bonsai?

Tags: pruning, bonsai

Could we grow bonsai with normal seeds and techniques to grow it? Which bonsai is best for indoor and acts as an air purifier? Instead of buying it, I want to grow my own bonsai. Please suggest some tips.

Comment: And please forget about the air purifier bit - a bonsai (or even multiple plants) will have only a tiny effect on air quality.

Comment: I have not done well with Bonsai, However I will suggest that you buy a plant . That will be enough of a challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bonsai are normal plants or trees, that we find in large in nature. The art of bonsai is to recreate the real tree in a miniature form in a pot. So any (real) tree can be used for bonsai. However, trees with large leaves are more difficult to downsize in good proportion, so starting with a tree species that has small leaves is a smart choice.

Growing bonsai indoors, is tricky. You can use tropical species for this, like *Ficus*. I like the Bonsai [Empire](https://www.bonsaiempire.com/tree-species/indoor-bonsai) website where they guide you for proper maintenance.